# Defined Momentum vs. Defined $k$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, momentum, normalization

In quantum mechanics usually we write the momentum operator $\hat{p}$ as:
$$\hat{p} = \hbar \hat{k}. \tag{1}$$
with of course:
$$\hat{p}|p\rangle = p |p\rangle \tag{2}$$
$$\hat{k}|k\rangle=k|k\rangle \tag{3}$$
But when we investigate the shape of the eigenfunctions with defined momentum $\psi _p (x)$ and defined $k$ ($\psi _k(x)$) we get:
$$\langle x|p\rangle=\psi _p(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\exp\left[i\frac{p}{\hbar}x\right] \tag{4}$$
$$\langle x | k \rangle=\psi _k(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left[ikx\right] \tag{5}$$

I find this unbearably ugly! In fact since the following relation holds:
$$k=\frac{p}{\hbar} \tag{6}$$
it would have been ***soo*** nice if both expression shared the same normalization constant, both $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ for example, because if this was the case we could have simply remembered (6) to switch between $\psi _k(x)$ and $\psi _p(x)$.

I don't really understand why the normalization constant changes, since, in light of (1) and (6), $\exp{[ikx]}$ should be the same as $\exp{[ipx/\hbar]}$.

Seems that the fact that (4) is not analogous to (5) makes working in the base of $\hat{k}$ not the same as working in the base of $\hat{p}$, which is strange considering that $\hat{p}$ and $\hat{k}$ commute and are practically the same operator..

---

**Edit:** to better show what's my problem with all this: consider a free particle with the following wave function:
$$\psi(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}} \ \ \ \ \ \ |x|<a\\
0 \ \ \ \ \ \ |x| \geq a
\end{cases}$$
and suppose we want to find, for this wave function, the probability distribution for the energy. Our best bet seems to be to perform a change of variable, since the Hamiltonian commutes with $p$ and $k$, doing this we get (feel free to check my math):
$$\psi(k)=\frac{1}{k\sqrt{\pi a}}\sin(ka) \tag{1'}$$
or
$$\psi(p)=\sqrt{\frac{h}{\pi a}}\frac{\sin(ap/\hbar)}{p} \tag{2'}$$
and then, since
$$E=\frac{p^2}{2m} \tag{3'}$$
$$E=\frac{\hbar ^2 k^2}{2m} \tag{4'}$$
we can fin the probability amplitude $\psi(E)$ either by substituting (3') in (1') or (4') in (2'). **The problem is the results are not the same!** What is going on?

Comment: Do you understand that the difference relies in the units, not in the math... $\hbar$ has units of action or angular momentum if you will, sometimes dimensionless units are nicer to work with, sometimes the opposite.

Comment: @ohneVal Problem is: in my edit we see that the probabilities seem to change..

Comment: No, they still don't change! You can calculate $dE= (2E/k)dk$ and $dE= (2E/p)dp$ using change of variables. The probability distribution can be written as $|\psi(k)|^2 dk=|\psi(p)|^2 dp=|\psi(E)|^2 dE$ and everything is still the same. This means that we need, for example, $\psi(E)=\sqrt{p/2E}\psi(p)$

Comment: This isn't a physics question but a maths one - consider for example that the pdf for a Gaussian variable $x$ with width $\sigma$ is $(2\pi \sigma^2)^{-1/2}e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}$ but if you rescale it to $y=x/a$ you change to $(2\pi a^2\sigma^2)^{-1/2}e^{-x^2/2a^2\sigma^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can normalize your continuous spectrum (and hence unnormalizable) eigenstates as you like provided you keep the *completeness relation* correct.

I always normalize my momentum states as  $\langle x|k\rangle= e^{ikx}$ with no inverse square roots. Then the completeness integral is $$
{\rm Id}= \int\frac{dk}{2\pi} |k\rangle \langle k|
$$
The measure $dk/2\pi$ is  quite natural  because it is the number of momentum states in the interval $[k,k+dk]$ per unit volume in $x$ space. If you put the $\sqrt{2\pi}$ with the state then you lose the ability to easily keep track of the $2\pi$'s. My way every momentum-conservation  delta function  comes with a $2\pi$ as $2\pi \delta(k-k')$ and so on. Keeping track of $2\pi$'s is important because $(2\pi)^4\approx 1600$ and losing this factor can really annoy the experimentalists who are looking for your predicted effect.

Comment: This may be nonstandard in some places but I like the reasoning!

Comment: Also, I don't think this directly clears up the confusion of the original question. You will still need $\langle x|k\rangle$ to differ from $\langle x|p\rangle$ by a factor of $1/\sqrt{\hbar}$, or else you will have to remember one integration measure is $dk/2\pi$ and the other is $dp/2\pi\hbar$, which is a bit more work in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of units. Many physicists choose to use units in which $\hbar=1$ such that the two expressions will be the same. Inside of an exponential, the argument must be unitless, which is why we must have $$\exp(i px/\hbar)=\exp(ikx).$$ However, $|k\rangle$ and $|p\rangle$ have different units; equivalently, $\psi_k$ as you have defined it is unitless while $\psi_p$ has units of $1/\sqrt{\mathrm{energy}\times\mathrm{time}}$.

It turns out that this "normalization constant" does not affect any of the physics involved in using these functions, so we don't often worry about it. I put normalization constant in quotations because momentum eigenstates are not normalized in the usual sense, so the prefactor is mostly a convention that ensures the overlap between two momentum eigenstates is a delta function.

The two expressions are equivalent in the sense that probability distributions are equal: $$|\psi(k)|^2 dk=|\psi(p)|^2 dp.$$

---

To answer the edit, the three probability distributions are equal:
$$|\psi(k)|^2 dk=|\psi(p)|^2 dp=|\psi(E)|^2 dE.$$ One has to use a proper change of variables to make sure, for example, that
$$|\psi(p)|^2 dp=|\psi(E)|^2 dE=|\psi(E)|^2 \frac{2E}{p}dp\quad\Leftrightarrow \quad|\psi(p)|^2=|\psi(E)|^2 \frac{2E}{p}.$$

Comment: check my edit if you want

Comment: Still no problem - recall that a probability distribution needs to include the measure, such as $dE$.